# 'computer programming is quite literally black and white'

Tags: meaning, idioms

I was thinking about this in the context of creating task requirements, having having to explicitly define how a program is to function.

One might say:

> Law is often described as black and white, for most cases it is quite clear whether something falls within the bounds of the law or not. However, unlike law, computer programming is quite literally black and white, there are no areas that are open for interpretation.

What I'm meaning, isn't that computer programming is literally the colours black and white. But that it is binary and deterministic, there's not room for interpretation. Whereas for other fields, even though law can be described as 'black and white' there are areas that are open for interpretation.

I think you could argue that the use of literally here is correct - that is, computer programming literally matches what the idiom 'black and white' is expressing.

If literally isn't correct, what phrase can one use here instead?

Comment: I don't think literally makes sense because computer programming doesn't inherently have the capacity to reflect colours, so it can't be black and white and, if you are using literally, then the figurative idiomatic speech would not work either. I would use perhaps 'essentially' or 'virtually'.

Comment: say *Unlike law, there are no gray areas in computer programmaing, no areas open for interpretation.*

Comment: Except have you read a programming language spec?  They are full of implementation-defined  behavior.

Comment: @jlovegren Sure - I probably would use an expression like that for this context. For this question, I'm more interested if you can use literally with an idiom like this.

Comment: Not to be a pill about the premise here, but in my experience law might more aptly be described as "black and white—and gray all over."

Comment: I think the best solution is not to use the idiom "black and white" at all, it only confuses what you are trying to say in this paragraph.

Comment: I'd try to shift the approach a little – your statement is that law is mostly black and white, while programming is always black and white, so maybe look along the lines of entirely/all the time, structurally/by design/inherently?

Comment: Programming is not binary, but computer logic is.  White exists only as a composite of colors, and since computer power supplies are well regulated, their bits are monochromatic.  Perhaps computer code is Black and Blue.

Comment: Saying that "computer programs are created using structured well-defined languages and usually describe deterministic algorithms" would probably do it for me. The black-and-white dichotomy should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

But haven't you heard? [*Literally* means *figuratively* now!](http://www.salon.com/2013/08/22/according_to_the_dictionary_literally_now_also_means_figuratively_newscred/) :-(

You could say:

> Unlike law, computer programming is figuratively black and white; there are no areas that are open for interpretation.

Personally I'd just leave it out; it doesn't add anything...

> Unlike law, computer programming is black and white; there are no areas that are open for interpretation.

Comment: 'literally' doesn't mean 'figuratively' that's an oversimplification. Literally can be used as hyperbole. For example 'The kids were literally bouncing of the walls'. What you're saying here, is literally that they were bouncing of the walls, but of course that's not what was happening, you were telling a lie for dramatic effect.

Comment: Re: the example you gave, that's doesn't work - because law can also be described as black and white, but not 100% so like computer programming.

Comment: Wha? The example ***I*** gave? I ***literally*** copied and pasted the "Unlike law, computer programming is [...] black and white" example from your question.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Law can be desribed as black and white (but it's not really), whereas computer programming quite [literally] is black and white.

Comment: Well then say what you're saying. If you want to make the point that law is sometimes claimed to be black and white but in fact there are areas open to interpretation, then you should say "law is sometimes claimed to be black and white but in fact there are areas open to interpretation". Don't make your point through the subtle placing of a particular adverb; people won't pick up on it.

Comment: I've updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

Of course using literally here doesn't equate to your what you say in the second part, which is this:

Unlike law, computer programming is **unquestionably** black and white; there are no areas that are open for interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps avoid the "B&W" metaphor and say exactly what you mean, e.g.: "While law is addressed to human beings, many of whom are trained in the art of construing and applying whatever it says in a sensible way, computer programming is addressed to machines with no such capacity for judgment, and therefore must be written to state exactly the task to be performed, and to cover all eventualities, including calling for human guidance when unexpected events occur."